# HTML elements generated by Javascript - now not functional

Tags: jquery, html, class

I am generating HTML elements using javascript. I applied the same class to all elements. I have a function that will execute when that class experiences the keyup event.

The problem is that my function is not recognizing the elements that javascript created.

See the example here --> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxTh5/6/)

HTML

```
<p>Type in the box below, an alert will appear</p>
   <input type='text' id='x' size='30' class='conv'/>
   <br/><br/>

   <button id='btn'>Now Click Me</button><br/><br/>

   <div id='mainform'></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
      var a =  "<p>The boxes below have the same class, thus they should show the alert when you type</p><input type='text' size='30' class='conv' id='a0'/><br/>";
      var b = "<input type='text' size='30' class='conv' id='a1'/><br/>";
      $('#mainform').append(a + b);       
    });

    $('.conv').keyup(function() {
       alert('it works'); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation (*As `.conv` being added dynamically*)

```
$('#mainform').on('keyup','.conv',function() {
     alert('it works'); 
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/VxTh5/7/

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @Sanya Please mark it as answer if you found helpful.tick mark under the voting arrows. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the class is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#mainform').on('keyup', '.conv', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('it works');
});
```

This will attach your event to any input within the `#mainform` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Do **event delegation**.

```
$(document).on('keyup' ,'.conv',function() {
       alert('it works'); 
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because your element doesn't exist at DOM ready, therefore when your handler is called, it doesn't find these elements. Event delegation binds the click event to an element that exists:

```
$("#mainform").on('keyup', '.conv', (function() {
   alert('it works'); 
});
```

We use `#mainform` since it exists at DOM ready. You can also use `document`, however, it is a very broad click handler.

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind event after appending created div, hence move your binding code inside button click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
      var a =  "<p>The boxes below have the same class, thus they should show the alert when you type</p><input type='text' size='30' class='conv' id='a0'/><br/>";
      var b = "<input type='text' size='30' class='conv' id='a1'/><br/>";
      $('#mainform').append(a + b);
       $('.conv').keyup(function() {
          alert('it works'); 
       });

    });
});
```