# button created via jquery not triggering a .click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery code to create a button for each row in a table:

```
    $("#add_to_rule").click(function(){
        var contact_type=$("#contact_types option:selected").val();
        var email_address = $('#email_address').val();
        var call_order = $('#call_order').val();

        var htmlstring = '<tr>'
        htmlstring = htmlstring + '<td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeruleset"/></td>'
        htmlstring = htmlstring + '<td>' + contact_type + '</td>'
        htmlstring = htmlstring + '<td>' + email_address + '</td>'
        htmlstring = htmlstring + '<td>' + call_order + '</td>'
        htmlstring = htmlstring + '</tr>'
        $('#rule_summary tr:last').after(htmlstring);
    });
```

Then, I've got some more jquery to handle the .click event for the remove button:

```
    $(".removeruleset").click(function(){
            alert('inside');
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            alert(id);
    });
```

The code to add a row to my table, along with the remove button works.  But when I click on one of the remove buttons, it doesn't trigger the click event.

As a test, I created a button like so, outside of jquery:

```
<input type="button" class="removeruleset" value="push me">
```

and it triggers the click event no problem. 
Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

I've tried changing the code to look like this:

```
       $(document).on("click", ".removeruleset", function(){
            alert('inside');
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            alert(id);
    });
```

But that gives me the following error :

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

I'm using version 1.5.2.

So, I referred to the article that's mentioned in some of the comments ([Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)) and tried this instead:

```
    $("body").delegate("click", ".removeruleset", function(e){
            alert('inside');
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            alert(id);
    });
```

That got rid of the error message but the event handler is still not triggered 
Also tried:

```
    $("body").on("click", ".removeruleset", function(e){
            alert('inside');
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            alert(id);
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to do event delegation, or attach the event after creating the elements on the DOM.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17046190/1823841

Comment: It smells like hugely duplicate..

Comment: I dont get how its gonna alert an id, that doesnt exist...your <tr> doesnt have an id

Comment: @KyleK.. He is not even able to alert('inside').. The answer lies in event delegation..

Comment: sorry guys.  i didn't know how to phrase the question to search for similar posts.

Comment: @markli that's why we're here to help `° ͜ °`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can try this for dynamic control.

```
$('#id').live('click', function() {

   ----your code--

})
```

else you can try this:

```
>>>$(document).on('click','#id', function() {

   -----your code ---

   })
```

Comment: 1) Question is a duplicate. 2) `.live()` method is deprecated.

Comment: +1 for the comment @RokoC.Buljan.. But you never know what version he might be using..

Comment: @writeToBhuwan in that case we're here to be *up-to-date* and suggest what's best. `| ̭ ̭°?° ̭ ̭|`

Comment: Right.. I agree with full respect to your comment..

Comment: I'm using 1.5.2 and I unfortunately, cannot just decide to upgrade.  It's outta my control.  Ends up that this answer worked for me. but i appreciate what you are saying Roko

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeruleset", function(){
            alert('inside');
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            alert(id);
    });
```

When you added the event to the element it was not existing. To make this work you need to use event delegation.

Comment: **Exactly** every day SO gets hit for about 20 questions on delegating an event for dynamically generated elements.The SO community is here to answer Q but also to close duplicates. Closing a question as `Duplicate` provides the OPoster with the related answer.

Comment: I've tried this code but I'm getting SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'. I'll google to see what's up.

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: 1.5.2 is the version number I'm using according to $().jquery method..

Comment: The you can use "live" function of jQuery. I recommend update the version of Jquery. 1.5.2 is very old version.

Answer (score 1):

hi another way is to do this  `htmlstring = htmlstring + '<td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeruleset"click=\"myhandler\"/></td>'`

where myhandler is a function

```
function myhandler(){
 alert('inside');
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            alert(id);
}
```